# yii2 how ovverride integer fields into model?

Tags: overriding, yii2

I read here

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6797

it's possible override a field,
to transfer it into integer

i want force ID to number

i try to add into model this function:

```
public function fields()
{
$fields = parent::fields();
    $fields = [
        'ID' => 'integer',
        'CODICE_SPEEDY',
        'DESCRIZIONE',
        'DESCRIZIONE_COMPLETATO',
    ];
return $fields;
}
```

but yii2 crash:
Getting unknown property: app\models\Interventi::integer

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Fields are used for renaming properties. They are not use for type casting. with this

```
'ID' => 'integer',
```

you are tying to make it possible to call `$model->ID` and that will show the table column `'integer'`

When you say `to force` what do you mean? that is something your database should do, or the model validation. You want `to force` to get an integer from what / where?

Comment: My problem is this:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6797

On 32-bit systems,
yii2 handles integer fields as strings
And so the json created by the service rest is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fields()
{
$fields = parent::fields();
    $fields = [
        'ID' => function ($model) {
             return intval($model->ID);
        },
        'CODICE_SPEEDY',
        'DESCRIZIONE',
        'DESCRIZIONE_COMPLETATO',
        'SERVIZIO', 'ASSEGNAZIONE', 'PIANIFICAZIONE', 'ESECUZIONE', 'ATTESA_CLIENTE', 'COMPLETATO'
    ];

return $fields;
}
```